# How to insert a new line and jump to it, in emacs?

Tags: emacs

It's exactly the same as eclipse `Shift+Enter`.

E.g. I have a some text:

```
Hello, *everyone.
I'm Freewind.
```

The `*` in the first line is the cursor. Then I press some key shortcut, it becomes:

```
Hello, everyone.
*
I'm Freewind.
```

Notice there is a new line in the second line, and the cursor is in the new line.

What's the key shortcut can I use?

Comment: I always use C-e and then enter.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`C-e C-m`

or

`C-e C-j`

Both will move to end of the line and add newline.  The second will also indent.

Comment: Can I map a key to do this job, so I just need to press once?

Comment: That is a key mapping.  Emacs allows binding commands to key sequences and most commands are two keys.  It's generally a bad idea to bind to one key since most of the one key bindings are taken by emacs fundamentals.

Comment: `C-e` invokes `move-end-of-line` and `C-m` invokes `newline`

Answer (score 11):

For completeness here is a function:

```
(defun end-of-line-and-indented-new-line ()
  (interactive)
  (end-of-line)
  (newline-and-indent))

(global-set-key (kbd "<S-return>") 'end-of-line-and-indented-new-line)
```

Comment: Thank you, but how do I use it? Just map a key to this function? Can I map "Shift-Enter" to it?

Comment: @Freewind answer updated

Comment: If you use `comment-indent-new-line` instead, it will also insert the appropriate comment characters if you're currently inside a comment.

Answer (score 8):

You can make something akin to a keyboard macro like this.

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<S-return>") "\C-e\C-m")
```

or indeed:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<S-return>") (kbd "C-e C-m"))
```

to avoid using two different kinds of syntax for keys.